# CakePHP tables join help

Tags: php, cakephp, inner-join, cakephp-model

new to cakePHP and trying my first join. I've got one table called users and one called projects. one user can have many projects, so projects has a user_id column.

Here is my action in projects_controller:

```
function index() {

    $this->set('projects', $this->Project->find('all', array('joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'users',
            'alias' => 'UsersTable',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'foreginKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('UsersTable.id = Project.user_id')
        )
    ))));




}
```

Here is the SQL dump:

```
SELECT `Project`.`id`, `Project`.`title`, `Project`.`created`, `Project`.`website`, `Project`.`language_id`, `Project`.`user_id` FROM `projects` AS `Project` inner JOIN users AS `UsersTable` ON (`UsersTable`.`id` = `Project`.`user_id`) WHERE 1 = 1
```

As you will see everything seems fine except its not selecting anything from the users table but it is joining it.

And here is my view:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>User</th>
</tr>



<?php foreach ($projects as $project): ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $html->link($project['Project']['title'], array('controller' => 'projects', 'action' => 'view', $project['Project']['id'])); ?>
    </td>   
    <td>
        <?php echo $html->link($project['Project']['username'], array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', $project['Project']['user_id'])); ?>
    </td>   
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Have I messed up somewhere? the view attempts to list all projects along with the user who owns it.

Thanks alot,

Jonesy

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If all projects have a user associated with it, then the inner join will behave just like a left join would in this case. If you are trying to list all projects by user, then you need to do a find on the `User` model and inner-join the projects table to it.

Comment: i updated my question, i want to list all the projects in the projects table and join users so I can list the project name and the user who created it so this is within the projects_controller

Comment: I've added SQL dump and updated view to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that what I wanted to be achieved by editing the projects model to:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className'    => 'User',
        'foreignKey'    => 'user_id'
    )
);
```

This did the trick!